# Display a td element on next line in the same tr

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make a table which looks like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Column 1                   | Column 2           | Column 3        | Column 4     |    
| Long Text                                                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Column 1                   | Column 2           | Column 3        | Column 4     |    
| Long Text                                                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The td "Long Text" shares the same tr with Column 1,2,3 and 4. How can I force the td to move to "next line" in the same tr?

I tried to put a {display:block} attribute in the td of "Long Text" by following this way http://jsfiddle.net/hDsts/. However, it doesn't work.

Are there good solutions for this?

Comment: It cannot be a separate <tr> ??
like:
!- col1 col2 col3  col4
!- veryyyyyyyy long text ?
!- col 1 col2 col3 

??

Answer (score 2):

```html
<style>td, th{border: 1px solid;}</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrry long text ?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
    <td>Col4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Verrrrryyy LONG</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Like this ?

You have rowspan and colspan.

rowspan does this:

```
+----------------------+------+------+------+
| Col1                 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+                      +------+------+------+
|                      | x    | x    | x    |
+                      +------+------+------+
|                      | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+                      +------+------+------+
|                      |      | x    | x    |
+----------------------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: if border property exists. The td of "Long Text" will be separated by a border (which I do not wish to implement). Btw, thanks for the tips.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand very well.
Something like this, you mean ?
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Comment: nope. It has to be in table. Column 1,2,3,4 and "Long Text" must be in the same tr. If "Long Text" is put in another tr there will be a border separating column1,2,3,4 with "Long Text".

Answer (score 0):

you can use colspan attribute like this

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=4>Long text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=4>Long text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the css for the border

```
td {
    border: 1px dotted;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDsts/354/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML tag `rowspan`.

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html